# Button a:hover and background color

Tags: css

I have a problem with my button. When I wish to click on my button, normally the color of the button which is "blue" should change of color in black.

It seems my background color (black) is not whole???

```css
.more-information{
 position:absolute;
 height: 33px;
 width: 158px;
 background-color: #005dbe;
   color: white;
   line-height: 33px;
   border:none;
 padding:7px 0 7px 0;
 border-radius:20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: bold;
}

.more-information a{
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

}

.more-information a:hover{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="more-information"><a href="#">Login</a></div>
```

Comment: the background is on the `div` not the `a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I moved most of the CSS from the outer div to the `<a>` instead and now it behaves as you might expect.

```css
.more-information{
  position:absolute;
  height: 33px;
  width: 158px;
}

.more-information a{
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  background-color: #005dbe;
  color: white;
  line-height: 33px;
  border:none;
  padding:7px 0 7px 0;
  border-radius:20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.more-information a:hover{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="more-information"><a href="#">Login</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```css
.more-information{
 position:absolute;
 height: 33px;
 width: 158px;
 background-color: #005dbe;
   color: white;
   line-height: 33px;
   border:none;
 padding:7px 0 7px 0;
 border-radius:20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: bold;
}

.more-information a{
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

}

.more-information:hover{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="more-information"><a href="#">Login</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.more-information a:hover{
```

to

```
.more-information:hover{
```

Comment: Hi! While this code may solve OP's problem, it is encouraged on SO to explain why the code is a solution. Code only answers are discouraged on SO, as they do not help OP or future visitors in the long run. Thanks!